# ios build to device with release configuration "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found."

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

Earlier i upload my apps from xcode to device for test with "Release" configuration(with distribution certificate and provisioning profile), i always installed apps via "Product -> Profile" on device.

Couple days ago i renewed ios dev program(also i renewed provisioning profiles and certificates and installed them, and changed configuration of targets to new certificates and provisioning. After that i removed old.) and now when i try to build app("Product -> Profile") with Release configuration i got error "**A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.**"

If i change target configuration  Release provision profile  and certificate to Developer instead Distribution all works fine. But when i will upload to app store there must be Distribution certificate and provisioning profile.

It's not good idea change settings every time when i need make appstore build. And i need "Release" configuration on device because  i use some code with **#ifdef DEBUG**.

I tried couple times clean all my targets, reinstall xcode, recreate certificates and provisioning profiles but still got same error "**A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.**".

Answer (score 0):

previous certificates were created by your device? if not ,request from your device. Also login on xcode using your developer account

Xcode-> Preferences -> Select user or login ->View Details -> refresh profiles (manual refresh is required now a days).

Comment: yes certificate was created on the same device. and i already logged in xcode, and already made refresh, even couple times.

Comment: make sure you you are using provisional profiles created after developer account renewal

Comment: yes it use, i just recreated certificates again, and created new provision profile for app, checked keychain, made refresh in xcode, changed target settings to new certificate and new provision, but still got same error.

Comment: from xcode organizer select device and delete invalid profiles . It might help. Everything else seems fine

Comment: removed all profiles from device(on device was only developer provisioning, i didn't see any production profile). After that reconnected device, but still got same error

Comment: If you are not seeing the production profile, then that is your problem.  Go into the ios Dev center and create a app store distribution profile for your app's bundle ID.  Then download and install the new profile and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: You must install a build of this app from [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) app (or at least is login to TestFlight app, maybe). Seems Apple using a "Testing Certificates" for Release configuration which only installed via TestFlight.
- Step 2: Removing installed build & run direct from Xcode.

I tried & app launching successfully.